# Rails: Add user to project's users collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, collections, call

I've got project and user models with belongs_and_has_many in them. Now I need add specific user into project's collection. I've got method in projects controller:

```
def addfriend
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.users << User.find(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to project, :notice => 'Added.' }
  end
end
```

and I've got this code in **show.html.erb** of project:

```
<select id="user_select" name="user_select" class="input-large">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <option><%= user.username %></options>
  <% end %>
</select>
<!-- button to addfriend method here -->
```

Now, I need to add button on mark in code (or somewhere else) with calling that "addfriend" method.

In **routes.rb** I've got:

```
 resources :projects do
   collection do
     get :addfriend
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an @project variable defined somewhere:

```
<%= link_to 'Add friend', addfriend_project_path(@project, user_id: user.id) %>
```

In your Projects controller action change the 2 firsts lines for this:

```
project = Project.find(params[:id])
@project.users << User.find(params[:user_id])
```

And in your routes:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
      get :addfriend
  end
end
```